# Docker compose build order

Tags: mongodb, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a problem with docker compose and build order. Below is my dockerfile for starting my .net application

[image]

As you can see as part of my build process I run some tests using "RUN dotnet test backend_test/backend_test.csproj"

These tests require a mongodb database to be present.

I try to solve this dependency with docker-compose and its "depends_on" feature, see below.

[image]

However this doesn't seem to work as when I run "docker-compose up" I get the following:

[image]

The tests eventually timeout since there is no mongodb present.

Does depends_on actually affect build order at all or does it only affect start-order (i.e builds everything the proceeds to start in correct order) ?

Is there another way of doing this ? (I want tests to run as part of building my final app)

Ty in advance, let me know If you need extra information

Comment: Why do builds depend on a database? Do you not have mock testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, `depends_on` is for runtime order only, not build time - it just [affects `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose stop`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).

I highly recommend you make all the builds independent of each other. Perhaps you need to consider separate builder and runtime images here, and / or use a Docker-based CI (Gitlab, Travis, Circle etc) to have these dependencies available for testing.

Note also, `depends_on` often disappoints people - as it just waits for *Docker*'s startup to finish, *not the application startup*. So your DB / service / whatever may still be starting up when the container that depends on it start will start using it, causing timeouts etc. This is why [`HEALTH_CHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) now exists (with a similar [`healthcheck` feature in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck))

Comment: Hm ok. Making the builds independent of each other kinda defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish. The tests need a mongodb database present to make real integration tests. I guess I could mock the database but imo that makes the tests worse. There has to be a way to do this without needing some monster CI tool like Gitlab.. or maybe I'm crazy..

Comment: Yes, you can work around this - e.g. manually start the DB container first (`docker-compose up -d db`) if you absolutely want the tests run in the `Dockerfile`.  (related:as above, perhaps make the tests wait until there's a useable DB connection, using `healthcheck` or your own test wrapper code)